# Authentification using two tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function traitement()
    {
        request()->validate([
            'username' =>  ['required'],
            'pass' => ['required']
        ]);



        $resultat = auth()->attempt([
            'username' => request('username'),
            'password' => request('pass'),
        ]);

        if($resultat){  
            flash("Vous êtes maintenant connecté")->success();

            return redirect('/accueil');
        }

        return back()->withInput()->withErrors([
            'pass' => 'Vos identifiants sont incorrects.'
        ]);
    }
```

I have two tables 1 describing personels like this

**personels :**

```
id || username || id_agence
```

**agence :**

```
id || code || amount
```

I use the foreign key `id_agence` which references the `agency id` in the `personels` table
I would like that when a user wants to connect he enters his `username` and the `password` of the agency where he is registered

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to use `auth()->attempt()` in your special use case. You can always default to using manual authentication.

```
public function traitement() {
    request() - > validate([
        'username' => ['required'],
        'pass' => ['required']
    ]);

    $personnel = Personnel::with('agency')->where('username', request('username'))->first();
    if (!Hash::check(request('pass'), $personnel->agency->code)) {
        return back() - > withInput() - > withErrors([
            'pass' => 'Vos identifiants sont incorrects.'
        ]);
    }
    // success and login manually;
    auth()->login($personnel);

    flash("Vous êtes maintenant connecté") - > success();

    return redirect('/accueil');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer but i have not specifie all the field of the different tables heir is the description of the two tables

### personals

id,
username,
id_agence

### agences

id,
amount,
conttact,
pass

I wanted to make a loggin system in witch a person enter his username and the password of the agency where he is registered to be logged

thank you